# Average width of a a zone

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, cost-path

How can I get the average width of a region or inside a curve?
or 
How can I calculate minimum,maximum, and average width of an irregular polygon?
I have attached a figure, I want to know 
how can I calculate width of yellow areas which are inside the polygons that exist in the main shape file.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a one-time solution, or is this going to be an oft-repeated task that you'll need a model or a script for?

Comment: is it possible to share both of them?                                                                                     this is an oft-repeated  but I am looking for  a  one-time solution too.

Comment: I would say at least 3 of the yellow patches are outside the polygon.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the thing that you mentioned. All these regions are not enclosed by the polygon.

Comment: You also need to define the rules for when you stop measuring. I.e. Why did you stop where you did with your yellow patch? What was your decision making process?

Comment: I used minimum bounding geometry (CONVEX_HULL), to separate the zones that I am looking for.

Comment: so now I have a group of polygon how can I derive the width? is it possible to calculate the minimum, maximum, and average distance for each of them?

Comment: Also your minimum width is always zero.

Comment: For a one-time width measurement, the distance tool is a good method.  Just turn snapping on and measure.  Not sure how to automate it, though.

Comment: I used path distance and calculated distance of each pixel horizontally and vertically by defining different angles in vertical and horizontal direction